# MacBook Pro stuck on white screen

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, restore

I have a MacBook Pro mid 2013.
As you may have guessed from the title, it won't boot.

Neither the Disk Utility boots.

The only thing I can do is boot from a bootable USB (CMD + OPTION + R) with OSX installer in it.
Problem is once it gets a little over the Apple logo everything becomes white, the fans start spinning like crazy and everything gets stuck.
Same thing if I try with the Internet Recovery OS (CMD + OPTION + R): it goes with the countdown, reachs the end, flickers, restarts, gets to the half of the apple logo, and then white screen :D

Any idea how to fix this MF?

Comment: If you're not booting into Recovery, there's a logic board issue.  It needs to go in for service.

Comment: Well, yes. I found out yesterday night that my mbp was recalled for faulty GPU from 2015 to 2017. Too bad I didn't know and it didn't give any problem back then.